# Using Ubuntu 12.04 in VirtualBox (OS X)

Tags: virtualbox, macosx

64-bit iMac host using VirtualBox 4.2.6 for guest Linux machine.

Initially installed 64-bit 12.10 virtual machine, no issues with install, never installed Guest Additions.  Eventually deleted VM altogether because the GUI was painfully slow.  I read that installing 12.04 would be an improvement.

Created new VDI, 50GB, fresh install of 12.04 32-bit.  The initial boot, live CD style, is fine.  Fully-functional display, mouse, keyboard, everything.  After the install completes my issues start.  It prompts me to remove install media (disc) and hit enter.  I have no keyboard input at this point, so I just kill it and restart the VM.

It starts up with the classic "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error.  I try to exit to console to do an `apt-get update` or install the Guest Additions, hoping to regain graphical support, but no CLI ever appears.  It's just a black screen.  To be clear, I'm also unable to boot from the live disc and "Try Ubuntu" rather than Install -- same low-graphics error.

Anyone know why I didn't experience this problem with my 12.10 install?  I want to stick with 12.04 because it seems so much snappier in the GUI.

(Apologies if this is redundant -- so many of these VirtualBox issues with little variance.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to pull up a console with:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

and then install the Guest Additions:

```
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
cd /mnt
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Then restart the Guest.